# react native autocomplete dropdown

Tags: react-native, npm, autocomplete, dropdown, libraries

i need a autocomplete dropdown like [**android autocomplete textview**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView)
but i can not find anything useful

i've tried using react native libraries like [**react-native-autocomplete-input**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-autocomplete-input)

- it's not a drop down, it's a flatlist
- it goes under other components
- not able to scroll items, it takes as much as space it's items need

i tried writing my own autocomplete but it has the same issues, i can't make it to have specific height and scroll inside other screen which has a scrollview to.
i used a textinput and a flat list to show data ... .

i think i have to use a modal or something

i need a component that works exactly like androids component or at least a good alternative

Comment: test my code and let me know if it is helpful or not

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AutoCompleteTextView in react native compatible with both iOS and Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49158554/autocompletetextview-in-react-native-compatible-with-both-ios-and-android)

Answer (score 2):

Yes you are right, you have to create a custom modal or something else. If you have a problem with react-native-autocomplete-input.

i m giving a simple example for you.

> Where i m using react-native-popup-menu for displaying types, you can
>   check this github repo and can customize its style as you want.

Run this code i hope it solves your problem.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
    StyleSheet,
    Text,
    View,
    TextInput,
    TouchableOpacity,
    ScrollView
} from 'react-native';
import {
    Menu,
    MenuOption,
    MenuOptions,
    MenuTrigger,
    renderers,
    MenuProvider
  } from 'react-native-popup-menu';

  const { Popover } = renderers

export default class Demo extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            userName: '',
            email: '',
            number: '',
            typedata: [
            {type: 'hii'}, {type: 'hello'},
            {type: 'hamzas'}, {type: 'hazily'},
            {type: 'hazing'}, {type: 'halutz'}],
            data:[]

        };
    }


    onSubmit() {
        console.log('sumbmit');
    }

    searchFilterFunction = text => {
        this.setState({
            businessType: text,
        });
        if (this.state.typedata.length > 0) {
            const newData = this.state.typedata.filter(item => {
            const itemData = item.type.toUpperCase();
            const textData = text.toUpperCase();

            return itemData.indexOf(textData) > -1;
            });
            this.setState({
            data: newData,
            });
            if (newData.length > 0) {
                this.menu.menuCtx.menuActions.openMenu('typeSearch');
            } else {
                this.menu.menuCtx.menuActions.isMenuOpen('typeSearch') && this.menu.menuCtx.menuActions.closeMenu('typeSearch');
            }
        }
      };

    render() {
        return (
            <MenuProvider ref={(ref) => this.menu = ref} style={styles.container} customStyles={{ backdrop: {} }}>
                        <View style={styles.wrapper}>
                            <View style={styles.inputWrap}>
                                <TextInput 
                                    placeholder="Username" 
                                    placeholderTextColor="#FFF"
                                    style={styles.input} 
                                    keyboardType="default"
                                    onChangeText={(userName) => this.setState({ userName })}
                                />
                            </View>
                            <View style={styles.inputWrap}>

                                <TextInput 
                                    placeholderTextColor="#FFF"
                                    placeholder="Email" 
                                    style={styles.input} 
                                    secureTextEntry 
                                    keyboardType="email-address"
                                    onChangeText={(email) => this.setState({ email })}
                                />
                            </View>


                            <View style={styles.inputWrap}>
                                <TextInput 
                                    placeholderTextColor="#FFF"
                                    placeholder="Type." 
                                    style={styles.input}
                                    value={this.state.businessType}
                                    keyboardType="default"
                                    onChangeText={(businessType) => this.searchFilterFunction(businessType)}
                                />
                                <Menu name='typeSearch' renderer={Popover} rendererProps={{ preferredPlacement: 'bottom' }}>
                                    <MenuTrigger style={{top: 5}} >
                                    </MenuTrigger>

                                    <MenuOptions style={{ paddingHorizontal: 5 }}>
                                    <ScrollView style={{ maxHeight: 200 }}>
                                        { this.state.data.length > 0 && this.state.data.map((data,index) =>

                                            <MenuOption key={index} text={data.type} style={styles.menuFirstOption}
                                            onSelect={() => this.setState({ businessType: data.type })}/>

                                        )}
                                         </ScrollView>
                                    </MenuOptions>
                                </Menu>
                            </View>

                            <View style={styles.inputWrap}>

                                <TextInput 
                                    placeholderTextColor="#FFF"
                                    placeholder="Address." 
                                    style={styles.input} 
                                    keyboardType="default"
                                    onChangeText={(address) => this.setState({ address })}
                                />
                            </View>


                        </View>
                        <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={.5} onPress={() => this.onSubmit()}>
                            <View style={styles.button}>
                                <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Submit</Text>
                            </View>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
            </MenuProvider>
        );
    }
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1
    },
    wrapper: {
        paddingVertical: 5,
        marginHorizontal: 20,
        backgroundColor: '#1A2854', 
        borderRadius: 10
    },
    inputWrap: {
        flexDirection: "row",
        marginVertical: 5,
        height: 38,
        borderBottomWidth: 1
    },
    input: {
        flex: 1,
        paddingHorizontal: 10,
        color: '#FFF'
    },
    button: {
        backgroundColor: "#BE39C5",
        paddingVertical: 10,
        alignItems: "center",
        justifyContent: "center",
        marginHorizontal: 20,
        borderBottomLeftRadius: 10,
        borderBottomRightRadius: 10
    },
    buttonText: {
        color: "#FFF",
        fontSize: 18,
    },
    menuFirstOption: {
        height: 45,
        borderBottomColor: '#D8D8D8', 
        borderBottomWidth: 2,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center'
      }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I had faced this same issue and created one component. You can refer [This question which I had asked.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49158554/autocompletetextview-in-react-native-compatible-with-both-ios-and-android) The gist for [AutocompleteTextView](https://gist.github.com/ashish-r/82f0aebe3e6d144b5ebdfa44642d3433)