# How to make a dropdown filter like Amazon App in React Native?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

So I'm trying to build a filter button that shows a screen below to let users customize the filter. I've searched for everything but couldn't find it. Does anyone have an example or suggestions? Ideally,  It's supposed to work like Amazon App's filter. Something like this.
[image]

Comment: Are you trying to implement FlatList with a search bar in the header?

Comment: Is this =>  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49158554/autocompletetextview-in-react-native-compatible-with-both-ios-and-android what you need?